# Did low $\small\sf{CO_2}$ levels affected Permo-Triassic mass extinction?

Tags: geology, paleontology, mass-extinction, extreme-weather, paleobotany

After answering this question:

[How did plants adapt to $\small\sf{CO_2}$ levels past 400k years? Why won't they do it again?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/how-did-plants-adapt-to-small-sfco-2-levels-past-400k-years-why-wont-they/15852#15852)

I know Permo-Triassic mass extinction is associated to a catastrophic event, but I wonder if, in terms of neocatastrophism, other factors, concretly $\small\sf{CO_2}$ low levels shown in this graph, were a prelude to Permo-Triassic mass extinction, affecting the basis of ecological chain at landmasses and oceans.

> [image]
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phanerozoic_Carbon_Dioxide.png). From Gradstein et al.,2005

[**Gradstein, FM, JG Ogg and AG Smith** (2005) *"A geologic time scale 2004"*, **Cambridge University Press** ISBN 0521786738](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/James_Ogg/publication/46658757_A_New_Geologic_Time_Scale_with_special_reference_to_Precambrian_and_Neogene/links/0f3175381b7a7b97fe000000/A-New-Geologic-Time-Scale-with-special-reference-to-Precambrian-and-Neogene.pdf)

Comment: No.  The Permian-Triassic extinction was marked by a substantial INCREASE in CO2. "...an increase in CO
2 levels by 2000 ppm..." (from the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permian%E2%80%93Triassic_extinction_event which is why this is a comment, not an actual answer).

Comment: @jamesqf my english use to be not very clear, but with *a prelude to Permo-Triassic mass extinction* I was refering to Carboniferous/Permian levels before the event. If the graph is related with the extinction or it was a totaly catastrophic separated event